# Self inner join, aggregate and sum of set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE aTable
    ("id" int, "idOfOperation" varchar(10), "uniqueName" varchar(6), "randomNumber" int)
;

INSERT INTO aTable
    ("id", "idOfOperation", "uniqueName", "randomNumber")
VALUES
    (1, 'operation1', 'model1', 3),
    (2, 'operation1', 'model2', 5),
    (3, 'operation2', 'model2', 43),
    (4, 'operation2', 'model3', 57),
    (5, 'operation2', 'model4', 65)
;
```

Constraints:

- (idOfOperation, uniqueName) are unique.

Table contains results of different operations (operation1, operation2) and which operation has multiple sub models (model1, model2, model3, model4) with some unique values (randomNumber).

What I need to achieve:

- Create a query which will find a sum of set of two operations (operation1, operation2) withe following output:
  `'model2', 5.18, 'model2', 43.2`

I already tried the following inner join:

```
select r1.*, r2.*
from aTable r1
         inner join aTable r2
         on (r1."uniqueName" = r2."uniqueName" and r1."idOfOperation" != r2."idOfOperation")
where (r1."idOfOperation" = 'operation1' or r1."idOfOperation" = 'operation2')
```

But the result contains two rows instead of one (with swapped values):

```
id  idOfOperation   uniqueName  randomNumber    id  idOfOperation   uniqueName  randomNumber
3   operation2  model2  43  2   operation1  model2  5
2   operation1  model2  5   3   operation2  model2  43
```

Expected result is:

```
operation2, operation1, model2, 43, 5
```

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: You can't store `3.14` in a column defined as `int`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query,

```
select split_part(idOfOperation, ',', 2) as col1, split_part(idOfOperation, ',', 1) as 
col2,  uniqueName as col3, split_part(randomNumber, ',', 2) as col4, 
split_part(randomNumber, ',', 1) as col5 from
(select STRING_AGG ("idOfOperation", ',') as idOfOperation , "uniqueName" as 
uniqueName, STRING_AGG ("randomNumber"::text, ',') as randomNumber
from aTable  group by "uniqueName") qry where split_part(idOfOperation, ',', 2) != '';
```

Snipping of your expected result,

[image]

Comment: please explain your solution

Comment: STRING_AGG function aggregates the data with respect to the aggregator defined in the group by clause. This will provide me the result of the combinations with respect to the delimiter specified (',' is used in the query). split_part splits the delimited value to a separate column

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are looking for transitions from `operation1` to `operation2`. One option uses window functions: `lead()` and `lag()` let you access the next and previous operation, that you can then then use for filtering:

```
select "id", "idOfOperation", "uniqueName", "randomNumber"
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag("idOfOperation") over(order by id) lagIdOfOperation,
        lead("idOfOperation") over(order by id) leadIdOfOperation
    from aTable t
) t
where ('operation1', 'operation2') in (
    (t."idOfOperation",  leadIdOfOperation) , 
    (lagIdOfOperation, t."idOfOperation") 
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2445934a702c84fbc65c9c59ddb6d98f)**:

```
id | idOfOperation | uniqueName | randomNumber
-: | :------------ | :--------- | -----------:
 2 | operation1    | model2     |            5
 3 | operation2    | model2     |           43
```

Side notes:

- avoid using double-quoted (case sensitive) identifiers: they just make things more complicated, for no obvious benefit
- column `randomNumber` should probably be `numeric` rather than `int`

Comment: not really, the output of above query is stil ltwo rows